# SQL query for ASCII Charcters

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am writing an query to replace ascii charcters. Before that i need to search for text that contains ascii character.

```
 SELECT * FROM __item WHERE description LIKE '%Â%';
```

How do i query to find descrption under __item table that contains the character `Â` ??

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: It list all the description that contain the character A not Â

Comment: Perhaps a collation issue?

Comment: How do i fix it ?? I need to get only description that has Â character

Comment: Try working with CAST(description AS BINARY) instead of just description

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM __item WHERE description LIKE '%Â%' Collate utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Actually the collation choice will depend on the collation used in your __item column (which is the same as the collation in your DB I assume)